# I want to move my SQL server from one domain to another

Tags: sql-server

I currently have two domains in my datacenter. Some time ago, it started to cause some inconveniences that I've decided to move my SQL server from one domain to another (where i have most of my servers). I'm already aware of the fact of changing the accounts SQL service run under. My concern is about services accounts. I have some of the other services (analysis, reporting, etc)  running under service accounts. What happens with these accounts when i disjoin my server from the current domain?

Comment: Do you have a trust between the two domains? Is everything running on one box or do you have a separate server for each service/function?

Comment: I have used trusted domains but I have considered moving from one domain to another because of the logins and permissions for dev guys. I do have all services in the same database server.

Comment: If the domains are trusted, then switching between them should not pose a problem. It would probably be a good idea to switch the accounts to the destination domain, but the services should still work as long as they are able to authenticate. I have run SSRS under a different domain account than the engine and server were on in the past without any problems.